# Functional dependencies with the same key?

Tags: database-theory, databases

let's consider a table with

```
carID | hireDate | manufactory | model | custID | custName | outletNo | outletLoc
```

I want to evaluate all the **functional dependencies** to bring in first, second and then third normal form.

- Functional dependencies

  ```
  carID,hireDate -> custID
  ```
- Partial dependencies

  ```
  carID->manufactory, model, outletNo**
  ```
- Transitive dependencies

  ```
  custID->custName
  outletNo->outletLoc
  ```

Since a car is in a outlet only I have in the partial dependecies this:

```
carID->manufactory, model, outletNo**
```

However this leads to anomalies in insertion (imagine adding a car with no outlet), so should not that be like this?

```
carID->manufactory, model
carID->outletNo
```

But isn't this still an normalisation anomaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misjudging what an insertion anomaly is. It does make sense for the FD to be

```
carID -> manufactory, model, outletNo**
```

since this is just a way to say that the same `carID` always has the same `manufactory`, `model` and `outletNo`.

Now, if you leave aside for a moment `custId` and `custName`, and you decompose the relation this way:

```
R1(carID, manufactory, model, outletNo), R2(outletNo, location)
```

you see that this is a fine decomposition that meets 3NF and is **free from insertion anomalies**: infact you just cannot have, for example, the same `carID` in two distinct `outlets`, or the same `outletNo` with different `location`.

You're right that adding a car with no `outletNo` would be no good since `outletNo` is a foreign key to R2, infact most DBs won't allow you to do such a thing. But this is a different story. Not providing values for mandatory fields is just wrong, and that of course doesn't mean the *design* of the database is not correct.